# Where is "close diff window" in Intellij keymap and/or menu

Tags: intellij-idea

There is a bug in latest intellij that "escape" no longer closes popup "diff" windows such as

- compare to clipboard
- compare with Git
- show History

I would like to do a workaround by closing the window via something like Option-F4 or Control-W.  But where is the Keymap entry for closing these windows? I have searched on `close` and there is no entry.

The last fallback is to go the snail way - to mouse over to click on the red "close window" button: but any mouse movements are slower than a keyboard shortcut.

**Updated information** Note: the normal "close window" keys (i am on Mac) do *not* work.

Here is the IJ bug entry  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142932

*Another update*  Here is key bindings: notice there is NO `Close Editor Tab` instead only `Close All`

[image]

Comment: Since these are gestures that usually are bound to your OS window manager's user experience, I wouldn't be surprised if they are not exposed at all.

Comment: @MarkPeters The normal "close window" gestures (on Mac) do not work here - I updated the OP accordingly.  If IJ were going to corrupt the normal operation then it should allows means to customize its behavior.

Comment: Because of the bug you cited, or by design?  On Linux, and with my older version of IntelliJ, Alt-F4 closes the windows you specify (in addition to Escape).

Comment: It started from the bug - which I filed maybe two weeks back. I can not find it handy - but will do so and update the OP.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using OS X Yosemite and pressing Cmd + F4 has the desired effect of closing the window. Cmd + F4 is bound to Window / Editor Tabs / Close.

Comment: are you on 14.1.4 IJ ?

Comment: on 14.1.4 there is no such binding available (see updated OP)

Comment: Yes, I am also using 14.1.4. For me, the binding is available.

Comment: In your keybindings, try searching for "Close".

Comment: Yes, i searched for close - the screenshot shows the result which does not include close window. I am on OS/X what o/s are you on?

Comment: As far as I can see, you searched for "editor tabs". Try "Close" as the search keyword instead.

Comment: I did not search for editor tabs - I searched for "close".  But the search pane does show "editor tabs". Not sure why . Trying again.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:
The related key binding is **"Close"** under **"Editor Tabs"** menu,
Then you can customize the keyborad shortcut as you want.

File > Settings > keymap >

[image]